# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Function'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new to Flutter. I am building a quiz app and have the following three dart files:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './answer.dart';
import './question.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  _answerQuestion(){
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {'questionText': 'What\'s your favourite color ?',
        'answers': ['Red','Blue','White','Black']
      },
      {'questionText': 'What\'s your favourite Animal ?',
        'answers': ['Dog','Rabbit','Tiger','Monkey']
      },
      {'questionText': 'What\'s your favourite Day ?',
        'answers': ['Tuesday','Monday','Sunday','Friday','Wednesday','Saturday']
      },
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
            ),
            ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List).map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion(),answer);
            }).toList()
    ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**question.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questions;
  Question(this.questions);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child:(
      Text(
      questions,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

**answer.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer  extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function buttonHandler;
  final String answer;

  Answer(this.buttonHandler,this.answer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(answer),
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)
        ),
        onPressed: () => buttonHandler,
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

when I run the application on my android in Android studio, I get this error:

> > ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY╞═══════════════════════════════════════════
> > The following _TypeError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#7f7de):
> > type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Function' 
> > The relevant error-causing widget was: 
> > MyApp file:///C:/src/first_app/lib/main.dart:7:10

Comment: answer by @nvoigt looks fine. Just a suggestion, it will be better to use null safety version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
onPressed: () => buttonHandler,
```

needs to be either:

```
onPressed: buttonHandler,
```

or

```
onPressed: () => buttonHandler(),
```

depending on whether your handler matches the required signature exactly.

In addition, this:

```
return Answer(_answerQuestion(),answer);
```

needs to be

```
return Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
```

Generally speaking, you have mixed up *calling* a method and *passing* a method as a parameter a few times, you may want to get more familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must pass a function structure instead returning value from the function by calling it.

You declared this function below:

```
_answerQuestion(){
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
}
```

and passed the return value instead of function structure like below:

```
return Answer(_answerQuestion(),answer);
```

As you can see the return value of _answerQuestion() is Null.
Change your code like this.

```
return Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
```

And you need to call the funcion in the Answer component.

```
onPressed: buttonHandler
```

or

```
onPressed: () => buttonHandler()
```

Comment: Pleasure :) @ZabihUllah

Answer (score -5):

Your code is working fine try flutter clean

Comment: it wasn't working. Fixed the issues as mentioned in above two answers